# Return content of cell based on location of other cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to build a function that searches an entire column, say column `A`, for a string of text. I need the function to return the value of a cell two places to the right of the cell that contains the string. So for example, if the string is found in `A17`, the function returns the value of `C17`.
I'm trying to use the search function, but I'm stuck. Can anyone help?

---

What I've got so far:

```
=SEARCH("search text"; $A:$A; MATCH($C$C ....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH("search text",A:A,))
```

If your Excel localization uses semicolons instead of commas for list separators then the formula would be:

```
=INDEX(C:C;MATCH("search text";A:A;))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Match()** and **Index()** .......................................

[image]

Note the asterisks.

Comment: @ExcelHero  I used the **asterisks** to match embedded sub-string.  Based upon the word *"contains"* in the original post

Comment: @ExcelHero  Your answer may be better as I failed to see the **;** in the original post.

Comment: Thanks! As a follow-up question: how would I return the value of a cell on any location based on the cell containing the string? So, if I want to return the value of the cell two columns to the right and three rows down, what do I replace `C:C` by?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I figured it out, I just added +3 after the 'MATCH' argument